# How to get Jquery autocomplete data as array?

Tags: jquery, arrays

i want to get the jQuery autocomplete data as an array and spliit the words. 
please advice

how to get this part print as array  `response( jQuery.map( data, function( item )` i want to get the data

```
response( jQuery.map( data, function( item ) {
     return {
               label: item.value,
               value: item.value,
               id:item.cat_id,
               category: item.category,
               desc:""
             }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = [];

$(data).each(function(i,el){
  result.push({label: el.value, value: el}
}

response(result);
```

On your select event

```
select:function(e,obj){
$("#labelfield").val(obj.value);
$("#categoryfield").val(obj.category);
}
```